# beginner calling functions in c++, code compiles math is wrong

Tags: c++, function, prototype, user-defined-functions

so i am new to c++ and thought i understood how to get the basics down in terms of functions, but im having a few issues. in an assignment, i need to return the value distance, radius, circumference, area, and diameter for a circle. currently using codeblocks, the code compiles but doesnt work properly. any help is appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;
double const PI = 3.1416;//constant global variable
double distance(double, double, double, double);//prototype for distance function after main
double radius (double, double, double, double, double);//prototype for radius after main
double circumference(double);//prototype for circumference after main
double area(double);//prototype for area after main
int main()
{
    double x1, y1, x2, y2;
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Enter the center X and Y coordinate of a circle (in that order with a space in between): ";
    cin >> x1 >> y1;//center coordinates
    cout << "Enter another X and Y coordinate in the same circle (in that order with a space in between): ";
    cin >> x2 >> y2; // second set of coordinates
    cout << "Circle's radius is: " << radius << endl;
    cout << "Circle's circumference is: " << circumference << endl;
    cout << "Circle's area is: " << area << endl;
    double diameter = 2*radius(x1, y1, x2, y2, distance(x1, y1, x2, y2));
    cout << "Circle's diameter is: " << diameter << endl;
    return 0;
}//end main
double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    double distance = sqrt(pow(x2-x1,2) + pow(y2-y1,2));
    return distance;
}//end distance
double radius(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double distance)
{
    double radius = distance;
    return radius;
}//end radius
double circumference(double radius)
{
    double circumference = 2*PI*radius;
    return circumference;
}//end circumference
double area(double radius)
{
   double area = pow(PI*radius,2);
   return area;
}//end area
```

Comment: What is the input you're using? What is the expected and actual output? You probably meant to call these functions and use the return value `cout << "Circle's radius is: " << radius << endl;` -> `cout << "Circle's radius is: " << radius(...) << endl;`

Comment: The input I have is in main, from the user. Im asking for a center coordinate, and another coordinate, all in one circle. That makes much more sense though how you put it. Thank you so much. I'm still actively working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;
double const PI = 3.1416;//constant global variable
double distance(double, double, double, double);//prototype for distance function after main
double radius (double, double, double, double, double);//prototype for radius after main
double circumference(double);//prototype for circumference after main
double area(double);//prototype for area after main
int main()
{
    double x1, y1, x2, y2;
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Enter the center X and Y coordinate of a circle (in that order with a space in between): ";
    cin >> x1 >> y1;//center coordinates
    cout << "Enter another X and Y coordinate in the same circle (in that order with a space in between): ";
    cin >> x2 >> y2; // second set of coordinates
    cout << "Circle's radius is: " << radius << endl;
    cout << "Circle's circumference is: " << circumference << endl;
    cout << "Circle's area is: " << area << endl;
    double diameter = 2*radius(x1, y1, x2, y2, distance(x1, y1, x2, y2));
    cout << "Circle's diameter is: " << diameter << endl;
    return 0;
}//end main
double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    double distance = sqrt(pow(x2-x1,2) + pow(y2-y1,2));
    return distance;
}//end distance
double radius(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double distance)
{
    double radius = distance;
    return radius;
}//end radius
double circumference(double radius)
{
    double circumference = 2*PI*radius;
    return circumference;
}//end circumference
double area(double radius)
{
   double area = pow(PI*radius,2);
   return area;
}//end area
```

**There were many problems in your code:**

1. Not calling the functions correctly

Consider these lines that you wrote:

```
cout << "Circle's radius is: " << radius << endl;
cout << "Circle's circumference is: " << circumference << endl;
cout << "Circle's area is: " << area << endl;
```

The problem here is that you are not calling functions how they are supposed to. You made function definitions at the end of your code and you named some of your functions as radius, circumference and area respectively. The problem here is that when you are trying to call the function, you are not sending parameters into your function this why it doesn't produce correct results. You have to pass appropriate parameters in the same order as they are mentioned in the function definition/prototype so that values could be passed onto your function to produce desired results.

2. Mathematical errors

Consider these lines that you wrote:

```
double area(double radius)
{
   double area = pow(PI*radius,2);
   return area;
}
```

Area of a circle = π x r^2

```
pow(PI*radius,2)
```

will return a value that is equal to (π x r)^2, so be careful while using mathematical functions.

3. Use proper programming practices

I won't consider it as a problem in your code but it will make your coding journey much easier if you learn to write efficient code. The more you learn, you will now the importance of using them as the difference in such basic problem is almost negligible.

Consider the code I would write for this question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

double const PI = 3.1416;//constant global variable
double distance(double, double, double, double);//prototype for distance function after main
double radius (double, double, double, double);//prototype for radius after main
double circumference(double);//prototype for circumference after main
double area(double);//prototype for area after main

int main()
{
    double x1, y1, x2, y2;
    cout << "Enter the center X and Y coordinate of a circle (in that order with a space in between): "<<endl;
    cin >> x1 >> y1;//coordinates of point 1
    cout << "Enter another X and Y coordinate in the same circle (in that order with a space in between): "<<endl;
    cin >> x2 >> y2; // second set of point 2
    cout << "Circle's radius is: " << radius(x1,y1,x2,y2) << endl;
    cout << "Circle's circumference is: " << circumference(radius(x1,y1,x2,y2)) << endl;
    cout << "Circle's area is: " << area(radius(x1,y1,x2,y2)) << endl;
    cout << "Circle's diameter is: " << 2 * radius(x1, y1, x2, y2) << endl;
    return 0;
}//end main

double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    double distance = sqrt(pow(x2-x1,2) + pow(y2-y1,2));
    return distance;
}//end distance
double radius(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    double radius = distance(x1,y1,x2,y2)/2;
    return radius;
}//end radius
double circumference(double radius)
{
    double circumference = 2*PI*radius;
    return circumference;
}//end circumference
double area(double radius)
{
   double area = PI * pow(radius,2);
   return area;
}//end area
```

At beginner level I would say you did a good job :D

Review the topic and come back to this problem for better understanding on the topic. Moreover, remember that practice is the key if you want to be good at programming. So embrace the grind.

Happy coding!

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your thorough explanation of my issues. This helps me immensely. Also. Thank you so much for catching the mathematical error with my area expression. I am trying my best to grasp the concept. When I say them out loud I can do it, putting into practice is where I slip up and feel lost! Though your breakdown helps so much! Thank you kindly, I hope you have a wonderful day

Comment: No problem dude! :)

Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are running into is that when calling functions in C++ it must be in format foo(bar) where bar represents your input parameter to the function. In your prototypes for example you define radius with 5 parameters but when you later call it it has no parameters to evaluate. Perhaps someone with more knowledge of C++ can answer as to why calling radius in cout results in the value 1 being returned however I believe this value is the exit code returned when the program attempts to execute the call. The proper way to call radius or any function in this case would be to provide it with the proper amount of parameters that it was defined to receive i.e radius(x1, y1, x2, y2).

Also a few things I noticed, the statement within area() to calculate the circle's area is incorrect you would want PI*pow(radius,2) as the way it is currently PI*radius would be calculated first and then that result is squared. Another thing is that in radius you have declared distance as a parameter that must be filled when I believe you meant to call distance from within the radius function and therefore can be removed from the prototype and implementation of radius. Attached is your code with the minor adjustments made to correct the issues.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;
double const PI = 3.1416;//constant global variable
double distance(double, double, double, double);//prototype for distance function after main
double radius (double, double, double, double);//prototype for radius after main
double circumference(double);//prototype for circumference after main
double area(double);//prototype for area after main
int main()
{
    double x1, y1, x2, y2;
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Enter the center X and Y coordinate of a circle (in that order with a space in between): ";
    cin >> x1 >> y1;//center coordinates
    cout << "Enter another X and Y coordinate in the same circle (in that order with a space in between): ";
    cin >> x2 >> y2; // second set of coordinates
    cout << "Circle's radius is: " << radius(x1,y1,x2,y2) << endl;
    cout << "Circle's circumference is: " << circumference(radius(x1,y1,x2,y2)) << endl;
    cout << "Circle's area is: " << area(radius(x1,y1,x2,y2)) << endl;
    double diameter = 2*radius(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    cout << "Circle's diameter is: " << diameter << endl;
    return 0;
}//end main
double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    double distance = sqrt(pow(x2-x1,2) + pow(y2-y1,2));
    return distance;
}//end distance
double radius(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    double radius = distance(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    return radius;
}//end radius
double circumference(double radius)
{
    double circumference = 2*PI*radius;
    return circumference;
}//end circumference
double area(double radius)
{
   double area = PI*pow(radius,2);
   return area;
}//end area
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me and pointing out some issues. I have read through these comments and am actively working on my code as well. To make sure I fully grasp the concepts in practice. I'm very much appreciative to all of yall. Thank you :] have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 0):

so I was able to rework it and I have more understanding about putting the function call into practice! I fixed the math and made a variable for radius in main, that way i can call it a bit more efficiently! I tweaked the function a bit too. I was getting a little lost in the definitions haha. thank yall for your help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;
//Part 1 - circle
double const PI = 3.1416;//constant global variable
double distance(double, double, double, double);//prototype for distance function after main
double radius (double, double, double, double);//prototype for radius after main
double circumference(double);//prototype for circumference after main
double area(double);//prototype for area after main
int main()
{
    double x1, y1, x2, y2;
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Enter the center X and Y coordinate of a circle (in that order with a space in between): ";
    cin >> x1 >> y1;//center coordinates
    cout << "Enter another X and Y coordinate in the same circle (in that order with a space in between): ";
    cin >> x2 >> y2; // second set of coordinates
    double r = radius(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    cout << "Circle's radius is: " << r << endl;
    cout << "Circle's circumference is: " << circumference(r) << endl;
    cout << "Circle's area is: " << area(r) << endl;
    double diameter = 2*r;
    cout << "Circle's diameter is: " << diameter << endl;
    return 0;
}//end main
double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    double distance = sqrt(pow(x2-x1,2) + pow(y2-y1,2));
    return distance;
}//end distance
double radius(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    double radius = distance(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    return radius;
}//end radius
double circumference(double radius)
{
    double circumference = 2*PI*radius;
    return circumference;
}//end circumference
double area(double radius)
{
   double area = PI*pow(radius,2);
   return area;
}//end area
```